# how to keep working on main branch without pulling from other branches

Tags: git, github

I made some modifications to my code on a branch other than the main branch and after committing the changes checked out to my main branch. but I can't keep working on my main branch without pulling the changes I made on the other branch.

Note that I don't want the changes from the other branch on main.

when I try to push my new modifications to the remote repository I get this:

```
To github.com:zkkamir/real_world_python.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:zkkamir/real_world_python.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

and this is my git log:

```
* 4bc6d0a (origin/smarter_searches, smarter_searches) Modified the code for smarter searches challenge.
| * ea21fec (origin/main, origin/HEAD) Updated the code according to instructions of smarter searches' challenge project.
|/  
* b43f9f6 (HEAD -> main) Finished chapter 1.
* 1fb8acf Installed dependences and started chapter 1.
* 01d6f48 Initial commit
```

Comment: Force push you changes if you are sure you don't want to keep what's on the remote.

Comment: Note that your forced-push has *discarded* commit `ea21fec`. If that commit contains good work, you should *recover* it before it goes away for real, using some other branch or remote-tracking name or similar to save it. If that commit is junk and *should* be trashed, do nothing now, and it will eventually be gone forever.